# Add values from a bigger table to a smaller table sql

Tags: mysql

I have the following table,

| Name | Day |
| --- | --- |
| John | Monday |
| Liam | Monday |
| Liam | Tuesday |
| Liam | Wednesday |
| John | Wednesday |

and the other table is,

| Day | Eggs |
| --- | --- |
| Monday | 10 |
| Tuesday | 15 |
| Monday | 10 |
| Wednesday | 30 |
| Wednesday | 30 |

I want to add the value of eggs to the first table. So it should become,

| Name | Day | Eggs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Monday | 10 |
| Liam | Monday | 10 |
| Liam | Tuesday | 15 |
| Liam | Wednesday | 30 |
| John | Wednesday | 30 |

Comment: lets say monday has 11 and the second 12, how do you decide which gets which ior doesn't it matter

Answer (score 0):

There are duplicate rows in the second table, so you can select distinct rows and then perform JOIN.

Let's the first table called `users` and the second is `eggs`. You can perform a query like this:

```
SELECT `users`.name, `users`.day, eggs_count.eggs FROM 
  `users`
  JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT `day`, `eggs` FROM `eggs`) AS eggs_count
  ON `users`.day = eggs_count.day;
```

Eggs values in the second table can't be different for the same day, because in this case, it will not be possible to match values.